# Incoming Valve Index VR Headset but now i need a 3 display-port solution with only 2 slots

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, virtual-reality

## Story:

I have two Acer Predator 144hz Monitors right in front of me. Both are connected to my Geforce 1080 GTX via Display-port.
My GPU only allows 2x Display-port and 1x HDMI.
Problem now is, i don't want to lose my 144hz on both Monitors because one of my monitors needs to get connected with HDMI for the Valve Index. The problem is Valve Index VR Headset only supports Display-port.
And when i connect one of my monitors with HDMI this one will no longer have 144hz.

I thought about a DP-Switcher. Then i can simply switch DP when i play VR and switch it back after my session.

Is this possible? Can a DP-Switch handle a 144hz to my GPU? Or are there any special HDMI cables that can support 144hz as well?

appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quickly answer you question, **NO, you cannot use a Displayport/HDMI converter to run the Valve Index, same applies to the VIVE Pro** , your best bet is to unplug one of the monitors when you use VR and plug the HMD on that port.

I would advice you to get a new GPU though, with the RTX series you even have the Virtualink port dedicated to the Index (with the non-included adapter available on Steam) .

Elaborating more on the gpu suggestion, not to burst your bubble but, to fully enjoy the Index you should really consider it.

I too had a gtx1080 and it was perfectly fine with the old VIVE that used 2x1080x1200 panels, even using 185% super-sampling! But then I switched to the VIVE Pro and, with no surprise, I had to under-sample to 75% to avoid re-projection. I can say for sure that my next best purchase was an rtx2080ti, bringing me up to 135% and looking great without re-projection again.

Now consider this: the Index has the exact same resolution as the VIVE Pro (2x1440x1600), so running it at 90Hz should equal to the same exact performance, I'm prepared to drop at least 30% super-sampling so down to 105% resolution, just to get to 120Hz and, to go up again in resolution and enjoy 144Hz, just wait for the next gen GPU.

In brief, **running the Index at 144Hz on a gtx1080**, without the motion smoothing crap and re-projection, would require you to drop to a **resolution lower to that of the old VIVE**! If you are happy with that then go ahead, I know I'm getting the next Titan when it comes out in November just to jump to 144hz and super-sample a little bit more.